If I missed shacharit, do I need to daven minchah as soon as it's permissable?
In the case where I overslept and missed shacharit, do I have to say minchah as soon as possible (i.e. minchah gedolah), or may I wait for my usual time? Certainly it's more practical to say it early, since one shouldn't eat before davening minchah in this case. But is there a requirement about it? If I chose to tough it out and wait until minchah ketanah or even plag haminchah, would that be allowed?

Why would it matter?

Are you sure you can't eat small things that are not bread?

Welcome to MiYodeya Elliot and thanks for this first question. Your question might be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.
